# Behaviour of restrict keyword inside structs

Tags: c, struct, c99, restrict-qualifier

**The scenario:**

Suppose I have a `struct` type holding a bunch of pointers, all of which declared `restrict`, and a function which takes a couple of these `struct` as argument as follows:

```
struct bunch_of_ptr 
{
    double *restrict ptr00;
    double *restrict ptr01;
    ...
    double *restrict ptr19;
}

void evaluate(struct bunch_of_ptr input, struct bunch_of_ptr output) 
{
    // do some calculation on input and return results into output
}
```

According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/cc-restrict-139391.html, `input.ptrXX` and `input.ptrYY` will be treated as non-aliasing.

**The question:**

Will the compiler treat `input.ptrXX` and `output.ptrYY` as non-aliasing as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should. For every pointer that you declare as `restrict` somewhere, the compiler can assume that it is the only access to the corresponding data. By declaring these, you actually give the compiler the guarantee.

If all compilers will take advantage of that information is another question. Passing `restrict` pointers through `struct` is not very common, so you'd have to see what your compiler does.

Comment: are you sure? please mind that input and output are passed by value, not as pointers

Comment: @Pandrei: The members of the parameter objects are `restrict `-qualified pointers. I'm not sure of the exact semantics, but I don't think that the qualifiers are simply ignored (except that a comforming compiler can ignore *all* `restrict` qualifiers).

Comment: @Pandrei, `restrict` qualification is a weird thing. In a sense it doesn't qualify the parameter itself but the object to which the parameter points. And regardless if the `struct` is copied or not, the function sees `restrict` qualified pointers.

Comment: Restrict qualifier behavior depends highly on the compiler, but in this case, I expect that the input and output are not considered as non-aliasing only the members of each structure.

Comment: If a `restrict` pointer is stored in an automatic object, the lifetime of that object will generally make clear the duration of the object's ownership of any storage occupied thereby.  If e.g. a struct containing a `restrict` pointer is created on the heap and used for awhile before the storage gets reused for some other purpose, how long would the pointer in the struct retain ownership over the objects?

Answer (score -2):

I think you have a bigger problem in your code: you pass two struct variables **by value** as inputs to a function

```
void evaluate(struct bunch_of_ptr input, struct bunch_of_ptr output)
```

The effect of that is that every member of the structure will be copied on the stack; this is a lot of wasted stack space and a lot of overhead for this function.
Furthermore the compiler will ignore the restrict qualifiers here because the struct does not expand like a macro, as far as the compiler is concerned, there are two arguments being passed in of type struct and there is no indication about aliasing.

This is probably what you wanted:

```
void evaluate(struct bunch_of_ptr *restrict input, struct bunch_of_ptr *restrict output)
```

Comment: I'm working with code which currently takes some 40 pointers as arguments. Packaging them up into structs is not intended to save on the stack space (for the time being), only to ease the call signature. In other words, yes, the code as given in my question above is as intended.

Comment: My answer is still valid; As far as the compiler is concerned, the members of  each structure will not overlap but the input and output members might. And  you can check the generated asm code to confirm that